# How to return Uptime of successful OpenVPN connection?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, openvpn, raspbian

I'm trying to figure out how to return the UP Time of a successful OpenVPN connection.

I've tried different variants of the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
TMP=$(grep 'tun0: link up' /var/log/syslog* | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d':' | sed "s/ "$(uname -n)" kernel:/*/")
WHEN=$(echo "$TMP" | cut -f1 -d '*')
SEC=$(echo "$(date +%s) - $(date -d "$WHEN" +%s)" | bc)
echo "Last link up: $WHEN ($SEC seconds ago)."
```

but it is only returning the uptime of the eth0 connection.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't find a way to do it without adding extra scripts, but this is the easiest way I could do it.

First add these lines to your *.conf file (make sure the up.sh and down.sh files have 755 permissions):

```
script-security 2
# Run when Connection is up
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
# Run when connection is down
down /etc/openvpn/down.sh
```

here is the contents of the up.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $(date) > ovpnTime.txt
```

here is the contents of the down.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat /dev/null > ovpnTime.txt
```

The up.sh script will add the connection date string to ovpnTime.txt which looks something like this:

```
Fri Nov 28 03:18:46 EET 2014
```

And then you can compare the date to now to get the difference which is "Uptime".

The down.sh script simply deletes the content of the ovpnTime.txt file when the connection is set to down.

I hope this is helpful to someone